# How to use standard search analyzer with keyword mapping?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, graphql

I have to use search_analyzer not with text but with type keyword as below:

```
"properties":{

"email" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "analzer":"autocomplete",
                "search_analyzer":"standard"
          }
}
```

But actually I have below mappping:

```
 "properties":{

    "email" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
              }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Analyzers only work with type `text`, not `keyword`. So you cannot define a `search_analyzer` on a keyword field. However, what you can do is to create a sub-field of type text like this:

```
PUT your-index/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "email": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "fields": {
        "analyzed": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer":"autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer":"standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When done, you need to update your data so that the `email.analyzed` field gets properly index. You can do it like this:

```
POST your-index/_update_by_query
```

When the call returns, the `email.analyzed` field will have been properly indexed with the `autocomplete` analyzer and you will be able to search on it using the `standard` search analyzer.

Comment: I can do reindexing of data with new updated mapping right?

Comment: I updated the mapping but still not able to do partial search...only keyword search is working

Comment: Maybe update your question with the search query you're sending

Comment: I am using phrase_prefix

Comment: The full query would be great! Help us help you ;-)

Comment: Do I need to do any changes in settings part?

Comment: I can't post full query here

Comment: It's hard to help you without you providing info. The query doesn't work, but you can't show the query 

Comment: Can we have personal chat