# Elasticsearch : Problem with querying document where "." is included in field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index where some entries are like

```
{
    "name" : " Stefan Drumm"
}
...
{
    "name" : "Dr. med. Elisabeth Bauer"
}
```

The mapping of the `name` field is

```json
{
  "name": {
    "type": "text",
    "analyzer": "index_name_analyzer",
    "search_analyzer": "search_cross_fields_analyzer"
  }
}
```

When I use the below query

```
GET my_index/_search
  {"size":10,"query":
   {"bool":
    {"must":
     [{"match":{"name":{"query":"Stefan Drumm","operator":"AND"}}}]
,"boost":1.0}},
"min_score":0.0}
```

It returns the first document.

But when I try to get the second document using the query below

```
GET my_index/_search
  {"size":10,"query":
   {"bool":
    {"must":
     [{"match":{"name":{"query":"Dr. med. Elisabeth Bauer","operator":"AND"}}}]
,"boost":1.0}},
"min_score":0.0}
```

it is not returning anything.

Things I can't do

1. can't change the index
2. can't use the term query.
3. change the operator to 'OR', because in that case it will return multiple entries, which I don't want.

What I am doing wrong and how can I achieve this by modifying the query?

Comment: Can you show the mapping of the `name` field please?

Comment: "name": {
"type": "text",
"analyzer": "index_name_analyzer",
"search_analyzer": "search_cross_fields_analyzer" }

Comment: If you have a `keyword` sub-field, it would have been easy to use it since you seem to be doing exact matches. But if you're not able to change your mapping and don't want to use the term query, I'm not sure how you could proceed, it's like saying, my tire is flat, I want to keep driving fast but I don't want to change it...

Comment: I got your point. But since analyzer is already in place, no point of using term query, right ?

Comment: It has nothing to do. You seem to be doing exact searches, so what's the point of an analyzer? What do they do?

Comment: We need to generate suggestion, that's why analyzer is important. Is there any other way  to do exact searches for a field which is analyed ?

Comment: For the purposes of matching, you can definitely create a keyword sub-fields all while keeping the analyzed text field at the top-level... it's definitely possible, but that requires a quick mapping update (which wouldn't change whatever you've done with the `name` text field

Comment: Could you please provide the definition of the analyzers `index_name_analyzer` and `search_cross_fields_analyzer`?

Comment: @Val : How can I create a keyword sub-fields to make it work ?

Comment: You can just add a `keyword` sub-field and then call `_update_by_query` on your index. See this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/61812876/4604579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured different analyzers for indexing and searching (`index_name_analyzer` and `search_cross_fields_analyzer`). If these analyzers process the input `Dr. med. Elisabeth Bauer` in an incompatible way, the search isn't going to match. This is described in more detail in [Index and search analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-index-search-time.html), as well as in [Controlling Analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_controlling_analysis.html).

You don't provide the definition of these two analyzers, so it's hard to guess from your question what they are doing. Depending on the analyzers, it may be possible to preprocess your query string (e.g. by removing `.`) before executing the search so that the search will match.

You can investigate how analysis affects your search by using the `_analyze` API, as described in [Testing analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/_testing_analyzers.html). For your example, the commands

```
GET my_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "index_name_analyzer", 
  "text":     "Dr. med. Elisabeth Bauer"
}
```

and

```
GET my_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "search_cross_fields_analyzer", 
  "text":     "Dr. med. Elisabeth Bauer"
}
```

should show you how the two analyzers configured for your index treats the target string, which might provide you with a clue about what's wrong. The response will be something like

```json
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "dr",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "med",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "elisabeth",
      "start_offset": 9,
      "end_offset": 18,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "bauer",
      "start_offset": 19,
      "end_offset": 24,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

For the example output above, the analyzer has split the input into one token per word, lowercased each word, and discarded all punctuation.

My guess would be that `index_name_analyzer` preserves punctuation, while `search_cross_fields_analyzer` discards it, so that the tokens won't match. If this is the case, and you can't change the index configuration (as you state in your question), one other option would be to specify a different analyzer when running the query:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "Dr. med. Elisabeth Bauer",
              "operator": "AND",
              "analyzer": "index_name_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "min_score": 0
}
```

In the query above, the `analyzer` parameter has been set to override the search analysis to use the same analyzer (`index_name_analyzer`) as the one used when indexing. What analyzer might make sense to use depends on your setup. Ideally, you should configure the analyzers to align so that you don't have to override at search time, but it sounds like you are not living in an ideal world.

Comment: I understand your point. But I can't share the analyzers because of privacy issue. I am curious to know about the possible solution. If I make the query like `GET my_index/_search
  {"size":10,"query":
   {"bool":
    {"must":
     [{"match":{"name":{"query":"Dr med Elisabeth Bauer","operator":"AND"}}}]
,"boost":1.0}},
"min_score":0.0}` , that is removing the "." from query, it returns nothing.

Comment: @fellow_dev It sounds very strange that the analyzers themselves are too sensitive to share on Stack Overflow. At any rate, I've extended my answer to describe how you can test the analyzers yourself and see how each of them will process your input.

Comment: I extended my answer to also describe how to override the search analyzer.

Comment: You are absolutely right. `search_cross_fields_analyzer` behaves exactly like you have shown. `index_name_analyzer` has stopwords configured, so `Dr` and `med` is discarded. But changing the query to `GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "dr med elisabeth bauer",
              "operator": "AND",
              "analyzer": "search_cross_fields_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "min_score": 0
}` - Still give no result. Why ?

Comment: You are specifying the wrong analyzer. You should specify `"analyzer": "index_name_analyzer"` in your query instead.

Comment: `"analyzer": "index_name_analyzer"` won't work, it generates `"tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "e",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 18,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "el",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 18,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "eli",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 18,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    },` .. and returns multiple documents. But why would `search_cross_fields_analyzer` not work ?

Comment: Setting `"analyzer": "search_cross_fields_analyzer"` has no effect, since that's the default search analyzer for the index already, as specified with the `search_analyzer` parameter in the index settings. The reason `search_cross_fields_analyzer` doesn't work is that it generates the tokens `dr`, `med`, `elisabeth`, `bauer` and requires all those tokens to be present in the document (due to `AND` operator). But `index_name_analyzer` discards `dr` and `med` as stopwords, meaning those two tokens will *never*  be present in a document, so the search cannot match.

Comment: Yes, figured it out myself, was a stupid question. I am accepting your answer as it clearly points out why the query does not work.